# Java library for Barcode scanner?

Tags: java, swing, barcode, barcode-scanner

Hello
I have keyboard wedge type of scanner. Necessary condition for it is that it requires cursor to be set on text field to receive barcode Number.
But i want to store scanned barcode number into buffer and used it later.

so is there any java library available which will help me in that aspect ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: This appears to be a fairly common question, and some very decent answers can be found in the links to similar questions in the right margin of this page.

Answer (score 4):

Zxing is a good option.

You can also try this:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Java-Barcode-Reader.shtml

Comment: @Jason: You can now relax. :)

Answer (score 4):

I just answered a similar question in depth [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146840/barcode-scanner-implementation-on-java), with an example of my implementation (I didn't want to use a keyboard hook because I didn't want to require focus on the program before interpreting a scan).

Answer (score 1):

One way is [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: : zxing is used to read barcode from images but i have barcode scanner to do that. I want java library which will read scanner output without need to have cursor on textField.

Comment: There is the class [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) that comes in my mind for a problem like this.