# Read USB Barcode Scanner Data in Java

Tags: java, usb, device, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode scanner (a Motorola Symbol LS4208) which scans codes and writes them where the mouse focus is at that moment( a word file, a form field). The scanner is connected via USB. 
I want to write a Java application that listens continuouslly and intercepts all the results received from the scanner. How can I write this program?  The scanner acts like a keyboard so I can use something like KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher, but how would I differenciate from a user keyboard input and the scanner?

Comment: in some other SO answer, someone told that you can differenciate the scanner from someone inspecting the speed the string took to be written (but I don't know how to get this from the event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Barcode Scanner implementation on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146840/barcode-scanner-implementation-on-java)